# Passing Query to Hive Variable in Hue (not able to see results)

Tags: hive, hue

I am trying to capture all column names of table in Variable

```
set col_names=show columns in Table_X;
select '${hiveconf:col_names}'
```

It doesn't work. It results literal value. I also tried .

```
set col_names=$(hive -e "show columns in Table_X;") ;
select '${hiveconf:col_names}'
```

It doesn't work. It brings back no values.

I am sure Its syntax issue and not limitation of Hive .

Comment: Not sure if you can do this. However you can use py script to collect all metadata and put into a table. Or else you can use hive metastore.

Comment: Unfortunately - I need to work in Hue , so my choices are limited

Comment: I do t understand How can you run hive -e command in hue? Anyways, sorry, not sure of any idea.